# setInterval not refreshing data in Jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Node app using Express and Jade. I'm pulling json data from an API and I want that data to be refreshed on the page periodically. So, my thought was to have an empty div, then inject the contents of a different route/template into that div and use setInterval to refresh it. It loads initially, but never refreshes. Here's the relevant bits of my code:

board.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  div(class='bodyBlock') 
    h1= title
    div#data
```

layout.jade:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type='text/javascript')(src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js')
  body
    block content
  script(type='text/javascript').
    $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval ($("#data").load("/currentdev"), 5000 );
    });
```

The /currentdev route loads data.jade:

```
ul
  each card in inprogresscards
    li(style='margin-bottom: 5px')
      b #{card.color} #{card.name} #{card.idShort}
```

So, like I said, /currentdev is being loaded into #data initially and displaying properly on my page. But it never refreshes. It seems setInterval is acting more like setTimeout...What am I missing? Thanks...

Oh, and here's the generated HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Current Development Board</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="bodyBlock">
    <h1>Current Development Board</h1>
      <div id="data"></div>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval ($("#data").load("/currentdev"), 5000 );
});</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing the function wrapper, like this:

```
setInterval(function() { $("#data").load("/currentdev"); }, 5000);
```

Otherwise your `load()` gets called immediately and its return value is what is actually used for the function argument for setInterval.

Comment: Yikes. So simple, I completely missed it. That was it, thanks!